# Bash shell: How to get the boolean vars names as string

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

```sh
for bool in $jobdummyjob1 $jobdummyjob2 $jobdummyjob3
do
echo "Boolean Value is $bool"
    if "$bool" ; then 
        echo "$alljobs"
        curl -X POST https://jenkins.xxxxxxxxx.com/job/$bool/build --user xxxxxxx.yyyyyyy@xxxxxx.com:ewfwedf3f234523555235235235235235
    fi
done
```

All I need is to take somehow the names of jobdummyjob1, 2, 3 and put them in the URL as a string. Those vars are booleans so when I do this I get true or false in the URL. I do not need the variable value, but its name.

First I run the 'for' and I go through each object. Each object contains boolean value. Then, I do the true/false check and if true, I need to get the string name of the same variable and put it in the URL . This is a Jenkins job.

Comment: Thia ia not a "Jenkins" issue. It's purely the shell is interpolating the variable at the loop, so it's passing the values. You want to "iterate over variables names, not values". [Lots of answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371966/echo-variable-name-in-for-loop) if you search for that.

Comment: This is not what I needed. I sent me how to print variable name, which is cool and I know that. I need to understand how to print the name and the value of the same boolean variable/. First I will need the value true or false then I will need its name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable indirection:

```sh
for name in jobdummyjob1 jobdummyjob2 jobdummyjob3
do
bool=${!name}
echo "Boolean Value is $bool"
    if "$bool" ; then 
        echo "$alljobs"
        curl -X POST https://jenkins.xxxxxxxx.com/job/"$name"/build --user xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com:xxxxxxxx
    fi
done
```

But it's cleaner to use an associative array:

```
declare -A bools
bools=([jobdummyjob1]=true [jobdummyjob2]=false [jobdummyjob3]=true)
for name in "${!bools[@]}" ; do
    bool=${bools[$name]}
    if ...
done
```

Comment: Third option: Use a variable name wildcard (if all relevant variables have, for example, the same well-known name prefix). `jobdummyjob1=true; jobdummyjob2=false; jobdummyjob3=true; for var in "${!jobdummyjob@}"; do echo "${var}=${!var}"; done` (A disadvantage is that you don’t have that much control over the order of iteration.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried your suggestion but with no success. I dig around for the wildcard and I am starting to think that the Jenkins is not supporting the wildcard vars

Comment: Which part is Jenkins and which part is bash?

Comment: I made it work with this script, but I face another problem, which should be the last one I hope:

The issue is that if the name of the boolean variable starts with number or has some special charachters as it is the case with "18dummyjob" and "18-job.com-test", it is excluded somehow and jenkins says that: /tmp/jenkins18288022382660040755.sh: 13: /tmp/jenkins18288022382660040755.sh: dummyjob: not found The numbers are literally skipped which changes the variable value. Do you have any idea what kind of string operation could I use in this case?
Also the boolean value is lost.

Comment: Bash variable names can't start with a number nor contain characters like `-`.